# SCRUM variation with daily goals?

Tags: agile, scrum, methodology

At work we are sort of following SCRUM but at the beginning of each week we plan a sort of sprint for every day.

For example, a regular week would be planned like this:

Day 1

- Story 1
- Story 2

Day 2

- Story 3

Day 3

- Story 4
- Story 5
- Story 6

... so on.

We use Pivotal tracker, and mark every daily sprint with a release, then proceed with the regular cycle of Start - Deliver - Accept or Reject.

As it is to be expected, most of the time stories take longer than expected or are rejected several times before completion and then releases all go to hell.

I know maybe Agile's philosophy is not to try and have this level of accuracy for every story, but we are trying to keep our commitments to a max in order to go as fast as possible.

Has anyone worked with a variation of SCRUM, or any other methodology for that matter that's optimized for daily sprints?

Comment: Agile recognises that there is inherent uncertainty in any task. This is because of technical risk and also because we may need to adjust what we do depending on the feedback we receive. This isn't a 'philosophy', it is a recognition of reality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because project-management should be asked at [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

2~4 weeks is normal length of a sprint and widely used in many companies. In your case it looks like a one week sprint with additional plan on each day in the week, which is a little bit intensive cause team might feel unnecessary pressure from daily release.

Based on you sprint setup, if "most of the time stories take longer than expected" as you stated, I would say that it's most probably something wrong happened in estimation. So there are several questions you may need to think about:

1. Who makes the daily plan?
2. Who gives the estimation of each story?
3. Who identifies the dependency among stories?

In my experience, one week sprint is ok but daily plan is unnecessary. The daily stand up meeting is already a "daily planning meeting" for the Scrum team. At this meeting team members pull tasks and make their own plan, which is reasonable. You may expect every task (or "story", in your case) should be complete during one day, but in fact this is very hard to achieve. Even for a simple "code change" task may lead to some review comments which suggests much bigger change than the task itself. So daily goal could be even harder to achieve than weekly goal or sprint goal.

However even though you couldn't achieve daily goals, have you check if your sprint goal is achieved at the end? I suppose this is more important because in theory in the end of a sprint something deliverable and with customer value should be demoed. And this is the goal that stakeholders really care about.

So my suggestion: take it easy on daily goal and focus more on sprint goal.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you need to stop thinking about your tasks/stories as sequential and instead think of them multi-day items that run in parallel.

The peer review and client feedback loop makes it very difficult to code, review and close tasks in a day so programming like you are with team members starting and completing multiple tasks per day is potentially always doomed to failure.

In our (i.e. my company's) experience it's better to pick a realistic number of stories for a fortnight (less than you think until you are confident of your team's velocity) and then review your progress both formally every two weeks and also on an informal basis every few days (just to make sure that nobody has got really stuck, or headed off-course too badly, on a particular task).  The daily stand-ups are fine for that quick sanity check.

One point to note, you say:

> but we are trying to keep our commitments to a max in order to go as
>   fast as possible

You don't need to programme your tasks as sequential items to achieve that; 1 task completed every weekday yields the same number of tasks per week as 5 tasks all completed on Friday.

Hope that's of some help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd urge you to take a look at [Kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban), as that's probably more suited to your environment, judging from your description.